# cross domain security error in jQuery script

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, grayscale

I have a multilingual WordPress site using WPML plugin which allows to have separate domains that point to the same WordPress install.
(EN) erikbijma.com
(NL) erikbijma.nl

I'm implementing this script to make grayscale images on the fly
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover

I previously tried pure CSS methods with the filter property but it slows down the site, plus it doesn't work in IE10
http://demosthenes.info/blog/540/Animating-CSS3-Image-Filters

I am serving images and script from the respective domain in each case (.nl and .com), so I don't understand why there's a security error.

Error messages in IE10

the error seems to happen here:

```
SCRIPT5022: SecurityError 
homepage.js, line 37 character 2

var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

In Firefox

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
[Break On This Error]   

var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

any help appreciated

thanks

If you want to make 30 dollars I posted the question here
http://www.wpquestions.com/question/showChronoLoggedIn/id/7830

Comment: and what is the error....

Comment: are you sure the JS ajax calls are trying to reach back to the same domain? you wouldn't get a cross domain error if the hostnames matched.

Comment: what does all the explanation about images have to do with cross domain script error?

Comment: sorry about that, added the error message from IE10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally decide to opt for a server side solution using the GD image library but the error mentioned in the original question was solved here
http://wpquestions.com/question/showChronoLoggedIn/id/7830

it was due to some URLs using www and some using the non www, as well as an error in the javascript